Why am I still getting account numbers that are in the pdf and in the excel sheet?
I was tasked with parsing a bunch of pdf files and extracting the account numbers from them. Then I am to take an excel sheet, extract the account numbers out of it and then compare the two and find the ones that are in the pdfs but not in the excel file. I've tested this on other pdfs and excel files but this one it doesn't seem to be working properly. I am getting account numbers that are in the pdfs AND in the excel file when it should be showing either/or I'm not sure where it could be going wrong. Any advice is appreciated.
For security reasons I removed the actual file paths to the pdfs and the excel file.
import PyPDF2
import re
import pandas as pd
import os

def pdf_pull():
    pdfFileObj = open(r"pdf_file", 'rb')
    account_numbers = []
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdfFileObj)
    for i in range(len(pdfReader.pages)):
        pageObj = pdfReader.pages[i]
        extracted_text = pageObj.extract_text()
        n_list = extracted_text.split()

    #--------   get account numbers from first page -----------

        if len(n_list) > 0 and "#" in n_list:
            acct_index = n_list.index("#")
            next_el = n_list[acct_index + 1]
            if next_el.isdigit():
                account_numbers.append(next_el)

    # #--------   get account numbers from second page -----------

        if len(n_list) > 1 and n_list[0] == "UDC":
            for item in n_list:
                if item.isdigit() and len(item) >= 10:
                    # print(item)
                    account_numbers.append(item)
                if "-" in item and len(item) > 15:
                    account_numbers.append(item[10:])
                if len(item) > 20 and item.isdigit() == True:
                    account_numbers.append(item[5:])
                    account_numbers.remove(item)


    # #--------   get account numbers with letters and characters -----------

        for a in n_list:
            pe_num = re.compile(r"[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+", re.IGNORECASE)
            if len(a) >= 15 and len(a) < 23 and pe_num.match(a) and a not in account_numbers:
                account_numbers.append(a)


    #------ ensure there are no duplicates or empty strings -------
    account_numbers = list(set((account_numbers)))
    for number in account_numbers:
        if len(number) > 22:
            account_numbers.append(number[4:])
            account_numbers.remove(number)
    for n in account_numbers:
        if len(n) < 1:
            account_numbers.remove(n)


    #------- extract data from excel -------

    df = pd.read_excel(r"excel_file")

    # # #------ delete columns that aren't the ldc account number -------

    df.drop(df.columns.difference(["LDC Account"]), axis=1, inplace=True)

    # #------turn column into list -------

    df_list = df["LDC Account"].tolist()


    in_excel_not_pdfs = []
    in_pdfs_not_excel = []

    # # #------- find differences -------

    for li in df_list:
        if li not in account_numbers:
            in_excel_not_pdfs.append(li)
    for an in account_numbers:
        if an not in df_list:
            in_pdfs_not_excel.append(an)


    if len(in_excel_not_pdfs) == 0 and len(in_pdfs_not_excel) == 0:
        print("There are no differences")
    else:
        print("These are in excel, but not in pdfs: ", in_excel_not_pdfs, len(in_excel_not_pdfs))
        print("These are in pdfs, but not excel: ", in_pdfs_not_excel, len(in_pdfs_not_excel))

pdf_pull()

I have tried to use set to find the differences and I've also tried to just use a regular for loop and condition.

I assume the issue is that one of the lists contains the account numbers as strings, while the other contains them as integers.

In that case, the list output would have shown quotes around the strings but not the integers.  Did the list output have quotes around the items of one list but not the other?

I just checked and they're all strings in both lists.

Are they also strings in account_numbers ?

yeah, both lists are all strings

Can you show the contents of df_list, account_numbers, in_excel_not_pdfs, and in_pdfs_not_excel ?

they both just lists of numbers in string format, I can't show them because they are actual customer account numbers

Without seeing the actual data, I can only guess that you've made some other mistake somewhere.

Try appending one dummy account number to both lists, and see if it shows up in the difference output.

"For security reasons I removed the actual file paths" if your security is damaged by sharing local file paths, then you should improve your security (however, sharing them here would not help; just a remark)

PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.
